# PHP call method from class dynamically

Tags: php, methods, call

```
class Test {

    function index($method, $params) {

        if (!method_exists($this, $method)) { 
            $result = 'method does not exist!';
        }
        else {
            switch ($method) {
                case 'add':
                    $result = $this->add($params[0], $params[1], $params[2]);
                break;
                case 'sub':
                    $result = $this->sub($params[0], $params[1]);
                break;
                default:
                    $result = 'no method selected!';
                break;
            }
        }       
        return $result;

    }

    public function add($n1, $n2, $n3) {
        return $n1 + $n2;
    }

    public function sub($n1, $n2) {
        return $n1 - $n2;
    }

}
```

How to call method other way. I don't want to use switch, becase when I add new method, then I must add it to switch also. I want to avoid that.

### Q: How to call method from class dynamically?

My Idea:

```
if(!function_exists($method)){
    $result = 'function not exist!';
}
else {
    $result = call_user_func_array($method, $params);
}
```

Comment: `$result = call_user_func_array(array('Test', $method), $params);` - see [the docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php) for details of callbacks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can do something like this,

```
function index($method, $params) {

    if (!method_exists($this, $method)) { 
        $result = 'method does not exist!';
    } else {

        $result = call_user_func_array(array($this, $method), $params);
       }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmm I was wrong...

You should replace the switch with:

```
call_user_func_array(array($this, $method), $params);
```

Comment: You should really add some explanation on how/why your code works